# Emacs GDB split window for every new visited file in resolution 2880x1800

Tags: emacs, gdb, emacs24

I run ubuntu 14.04 on MacBook Pro Retina and emacs-24.4.1.

With the resolution 2880x1800, the gdb (gdb-many-windows is non-nil) would split window for every new visited file.

When I lower the resolution, for example 1920x1200, the gdb open the new visited file in "Primary Source Buffer".

Anyone know how could I stop the crazy split at resolution 2880x1800?

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your .emacs:

`(setq split-height-threshold 1200)
(setq split-width-threshold 2000)`

Credit goes to the article [HOWTO: prevent Emacs from splitting windows](http://blog.mpacula.com/2012/01/28/howto-prevent-emacs-from-splitting-windows/) by Maciej Pacula